# Should I convert mongodb doc. _id to base64 string?

Tags: mongodb

Is there any security issue when server send `doc._id` directly to client?

If so, should I encode `doc._id` to `base64` string?

What's common solution for handling this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The `"_id"` of a document is generally just the primary key of a document and probably in most cases not exactly security sensitive. You need to assess for yourself if in your specific environment `"_id"` values must be protected for some reason. But I'd personally be much more worried about the payload of my documents rather than their `_id`s.

That said, MongoDB supports SSL/TLS (documentation is [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-transport-encryption/)) which encrypts the data as it goes across the wire so nobody (except for the one in control of the networking hardware) can just sniff your network traffic and read your `_id`s.

Also note that Base64 is by no means a way to encrypt data. It merely encodes strings using different characters but can be easily reverted into readable plaintext.